Select data for the current day
I have the following PostgreSQL table into which I insert values every hour.



currency
rate
date




EUR
1.21
2012-11-2


JPY
2.11
2012-11-2


GBP
1.3
2012-11-2


CAD
2.1
2012-11-2


EUR
1.21
2012-11-2


JPY
2.11
2012-11-2


GBP
1.3
2012-11-2


CAD
2.1
2012-11-2


EUR
1.21
2012-11-3


JPY
2.11
2012-11-3


GBP
1.3
2012-11-3


CAD
2.1
2012-11-3


EUR
1.21
2012-11-4


JPY
2.11
2012-11-4


GBP
1.3
2012-11-4


CAD
2.1
2012-11-4



Entity:
@Entity
@Table(name = "FXRATES")
public class FxRates {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "currency")
  private String currency;

  @Column(name = "rate")
  private double rate;

  @Column(name = "created_at")
  private Instant createdAt;
}

As you can see I have a duplicated values into the table because date is inserted updated every day.
How I can select a table row which returns a currency for the current date?

With the layout you have there, there is no possible way to know which record is the last for the day, because you don't have the time.  Wouldn't it make more sense to change the guy that CREATES the values so it only keeps the latest one?  You can do that by making that column UNIQUE and using INSERT INTO ... ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE ....

hm... I use this code to add a table record: FxRates fxRates = FxRates.builder()               .currency("USD")               .rate(123)               .createdAt("21-1-12")               .build();       fxRatesRepository.saveAndFlush(fxRates); Is it possible to enforce above limitation using Java code?

Not in one step.  You'd have to do two steps:  fetch the record; if it exists, update it; otherwise, add it.

You can't, because there are duplicates. There is no way to tell for sure which is the last one. You could assume the one with the highest ID is the last one, but that assumption is not necessarily true.
Instead, you can either add constraints so it is impossible to add duplicates, or you can make the timestamp more accurate so you know which one is latest. Which you choose depends on what you're using the data for.
Add constraints
Add a unique constraint to the table so there can only ever be one row per currency and date. alter table x add unique(currency, date).
Then, if you try to insert a duplicate, you get an error. If you want to replace the data for an existing day, do an upsert (an insert which will update an existing row).
insert into x(currency, rate, date) 
values ($1, $2, $3)
on conflict 
do update set 
  rate = EXCLUDED.rate

This is best if you truly only ever want to record one entry per day, and duplicate entries are mistakes or deliberate updates.
Use a timestamp.
This allows you to record multiple entries in the table and also know which one is the latest. alter table x alter column created_at type timestamp.
Then when you select, select only the last entry for each currency for the day.
This is best if you want to record multiple entries over the course of the day. However, it does make querying more complicated.

ok thanks for proposing the options but all of them are with native SQL queries. Are the solutions with Spring Data JPA/HQL? I want to do the inserts with Java code.

@PeterPenzov You need to make that in your question. I don't know Spring Data JPA/HQL, but SQL always works.
